# Triggers of "At system startup" not working

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I created scheduled tasks with trigger of "At system startup" on Windows 2008. However, it doesn't start after system starts. How to troubleshoot the issue?

I had to manually start these tasks in Task Scheduler every time after the system is rebooted.

Comment: It doesn't start or is there an error?

Comment: @sjzls what user are you trying to use? Just about anything but 'system' will make that happen.

Comment: Please add the relevant error from the event log to your question.

Comment: I'm using my own login.